# Multi threaded program on multi-core platform not printing output (std::cout) if I run a tight poll loop

Tags: c++, multithreading

As the OP states, I have multiple threads - two of them being tight poll loops (I need polling) with regular sleeps:- 1 seconds of sleep after every 10 seconds.

Program has multiple interim updates to be printed with:

```
std::cout << "progress report text" << std::endl;
```

Body of thread that polls, pretty much looks like:

```
void PollHardwareFunction ()
{
    lastTimeSlept = std::chrono::HighResClock::now();
    while (!stopSignal)
    {
        poll_hardware();
        // Process the data received from hardware

        if (std::chrono::HighResClock::now() - lastTimeSlept > std::chrono::seconds(10))
        {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
            auto lastTimeSlept = std::chrono::HighResClock::now();
        }
    }
}
```

Other threads are pretty normal that do few logical steps and prints status after each step.

```
void LongRunningFunction ()
{
    int dataCounter = 0;
    while (wait_for_data_from_hardware_in_concurrent_queue)
    {
        std::cout << "Data received: " << dataCounter++ << std::endl;

        // Process the data received from hardware
        std::cout << "STEP1 done." << std::endl;            
        std::cout << "STEP2 done." << std::endl;            
        std::cout << "STEP3 done." << std::endl;        
    }
}
```

This prints all messages as expected but only in bulk after 10 seconds. Making it look non responsive/stuck during this 10 seconds.

Program is run on following environment:
Compiled with GCC 6.2, run on RHEL 7, an 8 core CPU.

I notice that the program prints on the console only when the spinning threads go to sleep/idle. Once the busy threads go to sleep, all of the prints appear on my output console together. To add to it, data received from hardware is regular - say every 100 milliseconds.

With several CPU cores available free, why the program stays in non-responsive state till the spinning threads stop/pause?

Comment: Show some [MCVE]

Comment: I added some code to describe the OP better.

Comment: You need to understand much more multithreading. Read some [pthread tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) then improve your code (and design it better). C++11 threads are quite similar conceptually to pthreads. And your edited question does not show an [MCVE], because we can't reproduce that. You should give more details about your hardware (perhaps you should use [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)....)

Comment: My feeling is that you need to use [mutexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(computer_science)) and condition variables. But you should explain what `poll_hardware` and `wait_for_data_from_hardware_in_concurrent_queue` really are, and **give the real code**, as an [MCVE] that we could run on similar computers.

Comment: My program is bit better structured - it uses atomic variables and some of lockfree data structures I have implemented. I can keep learning multi threading;

my perspective here is to understand what can cause the programs output remain (feels) stuck where as std::cout << operator is executed (completed execution) with std::endl?

Comment: Without more details, your question stays unclear and should be closed. Consider editing it more.

Comment: Try inserting a `std::this_thread::yield()` or `std::this_thread::sleep_for(1ms)` after you poll the hardware and see if that changes anything. If so, it probably has to do with excessive blocking.

Comment: @Snps, i tried the yield statement but did not change the behaviour. I would not add sleep statements between poll because its a time critical path - thats the reason i need to poll.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, poll_hardware is a function from the hardware vendor's API that reads hardware buffer and pushes data into a concurrent queue. 
wait_for_data_from_hardware_in_concurrent_queue reads the data from the concurrent queue (blocks till then)

Comment: Then tell more about your hardware and your vendor. Think in terms of system calls (listed in [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)...). AFAIK,  `wait_for_data_from_hardware_in_concurrent_queue` is *not* a system call. I googled it and found nothing. So I voted to close your question (but could retract my vote once you give a real [MCVE]...)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, should that cause this? AFAIK, API to poll the hardware is merely calling device driver functions.

wait_for_data_from_hardware_in_concurrent_queue is my function that waits for data from a thread safe container.

Comment: I don't know, but I guess that yes. You don't give enough information to get useful help, and you probably need to use a mutex and a condition variable. See [pthread_mutex_lock](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_mutex_lock.html), [pthread_cond_wait](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_cond_wait.html), [pthread_cond_broadcast](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_cond_broadcast.html)

Answer (score 1):

From your comments:

> My program is bit better structured - it uses atomic variables and some of lockfree data structures I have implemented.

and

> poll_hardware is a function from the hardware vendor's API that reads hardware buffer and pushes data into a concurrent queue.

That sounds dubious. Did you write your own data structure or did you use an existing one? Regardless, please post the code for the queue. If the queue was provided by the vendor, please post the API.

> my perspective here is to understand what can cause the programs output remain (feels) stuck where as std::cout << operator is executed (completed execution) with std::endl?

You don't call cout from `PollHardwareFunction()`, so the issue **MUST** be from `wait_for_data_from_hardware_in_concurrent_queue` blocking when it's not supposed to. (If you want to be sure, switch `cout` to `cerr` to avoid buffering writes.)

The first thing I would check is if `poll_hardware()` is dominating a lock by re-locking as soon as it releases. You may have created what is effectively a spin-lock. This is why user Snps suggested sleeping for 1ms in the comments. 1 yield is not enough. I understand that your data is time critical, but you said 100ms, so theoretically you could poll ever 50ms and be fine. A few ms should be totally OK for debugging purposes.

Lock dominating can be both caused by and solved with a reader/writer lock. Reader/writer locks need to be custom designed with the characteristics of the situation in mind. (how many threads are reading vs writing? how often do reads vs writes occur?)

The second thing I would check are your assumptions about sequential programming and memory caching in your lock-free data structures. Loads and stores can be delayed, rearranged, buffered, etc. as an optimization. Everyone is your "frienemy"--the compiler will do this, then the OS will do it, the CPU will take its turn, and then hardware will do it too.

To prevent this, you have to use a memory barrier (aka memory fence) to keep any of your frienemies from optimizing memory accesses. FYI, mutexes use memory barriers in their implementation. A quick way to see if this fixes your problem is to make your shared variables volatile. **HOWEVER**, don't trust volatile. It only keeps the compiler from reordering your commands, not necessarily the OS or CPU (depending on compiler, naturally).

It would be good to know about some of your other atomic variables, because there could be a logic bug there.

lastly, here your use of `auto` is defining a scoped variable `lastTimeSlept` that shadows the "actual" `lastTimeSlept`.

```
if (std::chrono::HighResClock::now() - lastTimeSlept > std::chrono::seconds(10))
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    auto lastTimeSlept = std::chrono::HighResClock::now();
}
```

yikes! I don't think that's causing your issue, though.